# Python Twisted Deferred : clarification needed

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I am hoping for some clarification on the best way to deal with handling "first" **deferreds** , ie not just adding callbacks and errbacks to existing Twisted methods that return a deferred, but the best way of creating those *original* deferreds.

As a concrete example, here are 2 variations of the same method :
it just counts the number of lines in some rather big text files, and is used as the **starting point** for a chain of deferreds.

**Method 1:**
This one does not feel so good, as the deferred is fired directly by the reactor.callLater method.

```
def get_line_count(self):
    deferred = defer.Deferred()

    def count_lines(result):
        try:
            print_file = file(self.print_file_path, "r")
            self.line_count = sum(1 for line in print_file)
            print_file.close()
            return self.line_count
        except Exception as inst:
            raise InvalidFile()

     deferred.addCallback(count_lines)
     reactor.callLater(1, deferred.callback, None)
     return deferred
```

**Method 2:**
slightly better , as the deferred is actually fired **when** the result is available

```
def get_line_count(self):
    deferred = defer.Deferred()

    def count_lines():
        try:
            print_file = file(self.print_file_path, "r")
            self.line_count = sum(1 for line in print_file)
            print_file.close()
            deferred.callback(self.line_count)
        except Exception as inst:
            deferred.errback(InvalidFile())

    reactor.callLater(1, count_lines)
    return deferred
```

**Note:** You could also point out that both of these are actually synchronous, and potentially blocking methods, (and I perhaps could use "*MaybeDeferred*"?).
But well, that that is actually one of the aspects I get confused by.

1. For **Method 2**, if the *count_lines* method is very slow (counting the lines in some huge files etc), will it potentially "block" the whole Twisted app ?
   I read quite a lot of documentation on how callbacks and errbacks and the reactor behave together (callbacks need to be executed quickly, or return deferreds themselves etc), but in this case , I just don't see and would really appreciate some pointers/examples etc
2. Are there some articles/**clear** explanations that deal with the **best approach** to creating these "first" deferreds? I have read through [these excellent articles](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327) , and they have helped a lot with some of the basic understanding, but I still feel like I am missing a piece.
3. For **blocking code**, would this be this a typicall case for *DeferToThread* or *reactor.spawnprocess* ? 
   I read through a lot of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117587/twisted-making-code-non-blocking) and [this article](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/11/twisted-hello-asynchronous-programming/), but I still am not 100% sure on how to deal with potentially blocking code, mostly when dealing with file i/o

Sorry if any of this seems too basic , but I really want to get the hang of using Twisted more thoroughly. (It has been a really powerful tool for all the more network-oriented aspects).
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've got it right: you need threads or separate processes to avoid blocking the Twisted event loop. Using Deferreds wont magically make your code non-blocking. For your questions:

1. Yes, you would block the event loop if `count_lines` is very slow. Deferring it to a thread would solve this.
2. I used [Twisteds documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html) to learn how Deferreds work, but I guess you've already been through that. The article on [database support](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/rdbms.html) was information since it clearly says that this library is built using threads. This is how you bridge the synchronous–asynchronous gap.
3. If the call is truly blocking, then you need to `DeferToThread`. Python itself is kind-of single threaded, meaning that only one thread can execute Python byte code at a time. However, if the thread you create will block on I/O anyway, then this model works fine: the thread will release the global interpreter lock and so let other Python threads run, including the main thread with the Twisted event loop.

   It can also be the case that you can use non-blocking I/O in your code. This can be done with the [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html) module, for example. In that case, you don't need a separate thread. Twisted uses this technique internally and you don't have to think of this if you do normal network I/O. But if you're doing something exotic, then it's good to know how things are built so that you can do the same.

I hope that makes things a bit clearer!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and thorough reply, Martin!
1. and 2. Ok, the Thread/Threadpool approach *does* make sense in this case.

Comment: 3. I tend to be wary of threads in Python because of the GIL, but normally it **should** be able to cope with 3-4 threads running  `count_lines` methods at around the same time without messing up the Twisted event loop (the method is used in small "tasks" that then send the data from the files to devices via serial)

Comment: Thanks for the info on the select module, it seems to be "related" to the different kind of reactors in Twisted. I'll look into it in more details! For practical use, unfortunately it only supports sockets on windows platforms (hence the rather weird limitations I had when using twisted serial support on windows).

Comment: A sub question though : what if the `count_lines` (or any other method) isn't slow /blocking? Would **Method 2** be the "better" way to write a method that returns deferreds and that fires the deferred when  "computation" is done ?

Comment: If the function isn't slow, then I would just call it — when I used Twisted, I never used `callLater` outside of some test code.