# How to write node.js web for multiple user?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a basic web server

If the first user open 127.0.0.1/complex

and the second user open 127.0.0.1/simple

2nd user cannot see website until 1st user complete

How can I solve this problem?

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    if(pathname=='/complex')
    {
        console.log('complex');
        complexFunction(res);
    }
    else if(pathname=='/simple')
    {
        console.log('simple');
        simpleFunction(res);
    }
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');


function complexFunction(res)
{
    for(var i=0; i<9999999999; i++)
    {
        var complex=200000/3;
        complex*=200;
    }
    res.end('complex');
}
function simpleFunction(res)
{
    var simple=1;
    res.end('simple');
}
```

Comment: Just don't do such calculations. Or do them in a different thread, at least.

Comment: Node.js is single-threaded. Start reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16974649/271150

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node.js is a single thread process and is designed for async programming.
your for loop is blocking the whole process you need to split it up and make it asynchronous.

`setImmediate()` is one possibility or this.
see: http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    if(pathname=='/complex')
    {
        console.log('complex');
        complexFunction(res, 9999999999);
    }
    else if(pathname=='/simple')
    {
        console.log('simple');
        simpleFunction(res);
    }
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');

function complexFunction(res, i)
{
   if(i >= 0)
   {
        i--;
        var complex=200000/3;
        complex*=200;

       setImmediate(function() { 
          complexFunction(res, i)
         });
    } else {
        res.end('complex');
    }
}

function simpleFunction(res)
{
    var simple=1;
    res.end('simple');
}
```

Comment: It works, but it makes the program very difficult to read. Now I understand why node.js is not suitable for website.

Comment: @CLSo.. doesn't mean node is not suitable.. its just  different than other languages