# Developing Applications with nodejs

Tags: input, web-applications, output, cpu

What are CPU intensive applications and why can't I develop CPU intensive apps with Nodejs ?

Comment: You can refer to this stackoverflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16974649/4510870) by poke

Answer (score 0):

A simple but not complete answer to this question is: `Single Threaded Event Loop Model architecture` of NodeJS.
NodeJS does not use the complete power of a CPU because it can only be executed on one thread.