# Does node.js is creating an instance of a server for each client?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, server, instance, clients

Does node.js is create an instance of a node.js for each client, or there is only one instance of node.js server for a whole variety of clients and unique instances created only for paths for each client ?

Answer (score 2):

Nodejs doesn't create a new server instance for each client, neither do other options out there.

You're probably thinking of **multithreading** as traditionally multithreaded web servers create a new thread for each client request, however since node.js runs JavaScript which is single threaded the answer is no - every client request is handled by the same single thread.

That is why Node.js and JavaScript are often associated with the word **blocking** referring to the fact that if you write code that takes a long time to complete, it will block all the other users from getting served. You don't however have to worry about blocking when performing I/O since Node.js (JavaScript) is asynchronous - meaning that client requests won't block each other when performing I/O operations such as network requests or disk reads.

To read more on Node.js being single threaded, see this S/O answer: [Why is Node.js single threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959663/why-is-node-js-single-threaded)

Comment: `multithreaded web servers create a new thread for each client request` not exactly. it's an old approach.