# How to execute parallel query in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have created a function in nodejs which return below object **QueryName** and **Query**

```
{"QueryName":"a","Query":"SELECT something from bar"} 
{"QueryName":"b","Query":"SELECT something from bar"} 
{"QueryName":"c","Query":"SELECT something from bar"} 
{"QueryName":"d","Query":"SELECT something from bar"}
```

Also, i have created another function to get the query result.

**Code is so far**

```
executeQuery(connection, query, config.dbtype, response, function (error, data) {

});

function executeQuery(connection, query, dbtype, response, callback) {
    DB_OPERATIONS.executeOperations(connection, APP_CONSTANT.findall, query, dbtype, null, null, "", function (error, data) {
        callback(error, data);
    });
};

FIND_ALL.findAllRecords(connection, query, dbtype, function(error, result) {
    callback(error, result);
});
```

Time taking to execute each Query is 5 seconds, total time 20 Seconds.

How can i execute each query parallel in nodejs ?? thenafter instead of 20 seconds, maximum it will takes 5 seconds to get all queries data.

Comment: You can fork new processes for running the queries parallel. But keep your machine power in mind.

Comment: every IO operation(like go to db and do query ) in nodejs is parallel by default in node js

Comment: you can use promise based functions

Answer (score 1):

As @zabusa pointed out in the comments you could use promise based functions.

Here are some examples

```
var queries = [{"QueryName":"a","Query":"SELECT something from bar"} 
{"QueryName":"b","Query":"SELECT something from bar"} 
{"QueryName":"c","Query":"SELECT something from bar"} 
{"QueryName":"d","Query":"SELECT something from bar"}]


//Promisified executeQuery
function executeQueryAsync(connection, query, dbtype, response) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        DB_OPERATIONS.executeOperations(connection, APP_CONSTANT.findall, query.Query, dbtype, null, null, "", function (error, data) {
            var result = {
                QueryName: query.QueryName
            }
            if(error){
                reject(error);
                return;
            }
            result.data = data;
            resolve(result);
        });
    })
};

// Promise with callback
function executeMultipleQueries(callback){

    var promises = [];
    queries.forEach(function(query){
        promises.push(executeQueryAsync(connection, query, config.dbtype, response))
    })

    Promise.all(promises).then(callback)

}

executeMultipleQueries(function(results){
    // results[0].QueryName is a
    // results[1].QueryName is b
    // results[2].QueryName is c
    //actually there is no need to create a result object in the promise, 
    //if we only revolved the data the result array will have them in the order with pushed them in the promises array 
})


//Full Promise

function executeMultipleQueriesPromise(){

    var promises = [];
    queries.forEach(function(query){
        promises.push(executeQueryAsync(connection, query, config.dbtype, response))
    })

    return Promise.all(promises)

}

executeMultipleQueriesPromise().then(function(results){
    // results[0].QueryName is a
    // results[1].QueryName is b
    // results[2].QueryName is c
    //actually there is no need to create a result object in the promise, 
    //if we only revolved the data the result array will have them in the order with pushed them in the promises array 
})
```

Comment: It'll not necessarily run in parallel, promise.all has not this guarantee

Comment: Hmmm...the code inside the Promise constructor runs when the promise is created and it runs synchronously, so even without ```Promise.All``` everything still runs and its parallel.

Comment: Concurrecy and Parallelism are different concepts. https://bytearcher.com/articles/parallel-vs-concurrent/

Comment: Yea, that debate again. Its true JavaScript is concurrent since its single threaded, but again if you run 10 queries that will take average 5 minutes foreach to complete, do these queries run in the database at the same time? The answer is, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more processes with [Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). You can see more about multi thread in node in this thread [Why is Node.js single threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959663/why-is-node-js-single-threaded). Hope its help you.